# Keep getting 404 eventhough I mapped my routes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have been dealing with some issues about routes. I have defined the routes but I keep getting 404. Here are the routes :

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Login" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Home",
    url: "{controller}/{Date}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Home", Date = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Calendar",
    url: "{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Calendar", action = "Index" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Act",
    url: "{controller}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Act", action = "New" }
);

localhost:51081/login works! 
localhost:51081/Home/25.04.2013 works! 
localhost:51081/act doesnt work! 
localhost:51081/calendar/index doesnt work!
```

Here "login" and "home" works but "calendar" and "act" doesnt. When I move "calendar" mapping to the top then "home" mapping doesnt work. how do you map your pages?

Basically I dont want action name to appear on the url ex : `http://localhost:51081/Home/Home/25.04.2013.` I want to see it like `http://localhost:51081/Home/25.04.2013 or http://localhost:51081/calendar`

Comment: Default is usually the last route defined, try moving it below act

Comment: what is the routes that fail? also: your "Act" route is basically a re-statement of the first route, with a different default; well - tough: by that time, it will have already hit the first route. Likewise, your "Calendar" route is a restatement of the *second* route. Just with different names.

Comment: Please mention the url that you are trying to access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like @MarcGravell says:  you only add special rules for the exceptions

In your case routes Calendar and Home are the same.
You can map your routes more specific by replacing {controller} with the Home, cause that route isn't that dynamic and is really an exception(it ignores the action)

```
  routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Home",
            url: "Home/{Date}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Home", Date = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Act is the same as calendar so you don't need two routes for those. Just call Act/New instead of only Act.

For the Default use:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Login" }
);
```

And put it at the bottom of your routes off course.

Comment: That s a good answer and very useful, thanks. But I want to handle my routes more dynamic. If I do as you said, then I d have to write a lot of routing

Comment: @Ktt no, you only add special rules for the *exceptions*; the default is there to catch the rest. Actually, on my projects we do the route-mapping differently - we annotate the actions themselves with the pattern we want them to match. Works really well.

Comment: then is this going to hande all? :  *routes.MapRoute(
               name: "Default",
               url: "{controller}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Login" }
           );*  it works for *localhost:bla/login* but doesnt for *localhost:bla/act*

Comment: how do you make the action parameterized? @MarcGravell's first routing  code explains a lot and it will always look for "Login" as action. Is it possible to make it changable? Ex as I mentioned, *localhost:bla/Act* . According to MarcGravell's explanation, "Act" controllor won't work because there is no action called "Login" in "Act" controller.

Comment: Action is a parameter : url: "{controller}/{action}",
Only if it doesnt find the parameter it will default use Login

Comment: So as I understand, you have to specify your action name such as * url: "{controller}/{action}"* .

Answer (score 2):

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Login" }
        );
```

This defines a route that matches `/` and `/anything`; the `/` will try to use `LoginController.Login`, and `/anything` will try to use `anythingController.Login`. Note that at no point does this route allow it to pick up any "action" other than `Login`.

If you trow all of those away, and use something like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
         name: "Default",
         url: "{controller}/{action}",
         defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
         );
```

then that will match any of `/`, `/anything` and `/anything/anythingelse`.

- `/` will map to `HomeController.Index`
- `/anything` will map to `anythingController.Index`
- `/anything/anythingelse` will map to `anythingController.anythingelse`

Hopefully that explains how the mapping works in terms of defaults.

If you have any *specific* routes, they should be added **before** this blanket default.

Comment: I almost understand it,thanks. So then what is the difference between   **routes.MapRoute(
               name: "Default", 
               url: "{controller}/{action}", 
               defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Login"}
           );

          routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Home",
                url: "{controller}/{Date}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Home", Date = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );**

Comment: @Ktt the second always uses the action `Home`, no matter what is specified - the first takes the action from the second part of the url, defaulting to `Login`; the first defaults the route `/` to the `LoginController`, the second defaults the route `/` to the `HomeController`; However - note that they are processed in insertion order: the first match wins.

Comment: Basically I dont want action name to appear on the url ex : `http://localhost:51081/Home/Home/25.04.2013.` I want to see it like `http://localhost:51081/Home/25.04.2013 or http://localhost:51081/calendar`

Comment: @Ktt then you probably want the *default* route for everything else, but **before** that you want to add a route for `Home/{Date}` with default that specifies controller = `Home` and action = `YourMethodName` - exactly like Ruben-J has illustrated, in fact

Answer (score 1):

Remember that asp.net routes are evaluated in the order in which you add them to the `MapRoute` table.

Your "default" and "act" routes are the same, since they have the same pattern.  "Act" will probably never get hit.

Also, your "default" route is pretty generic, and most requests will satisfy it.  You should add your routes in order of most specific (e.g. hard-coded routes) to least specific (e.g. all placeholders).

So if I have a request of foo/bar, it will fall to your "default" route since "foo" will be interpreted as the controller -- it's then going to look for a resource of "bar" which probably doesn't exist.  So you'll get a 404.

Your "home" and "calendar" routes are also the same pattern, so only one will get hit (which will be the first defined).

Make your routes more specific, and define them from most specific to least.

Good luck!